# ResourceLoader.GetString With Colon

Tags: c#, uwp

I got an `ArgumentException (Value does not fall within the expected range.)` when I am doing this:

```
         var str = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString(resource);
```

where `resource` has the value of `"Playlists:"`.

So I am guessing that colon is not allowed in the `ResourceLoader`, because I have another `resource` with a colon in it that I want to retrieve but I indeed got nothing.

So how should I use colon in `ResourceLoader.GetString`?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark... Have you tried `"Playlists%3A"` ? Since these are treated as URI fragments

Comment: @TheGeneral Thank you it works! I didn't try it because I don't know `%3A` stands for colon at all. Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a stab in the dark... Have you tried `"Playlists%3A"` ? Since these are treated as URI fragments.

[ResourceLoader.GetString(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader.getstring)

> **Note**
>
> **The resource identifier is treated as a Uniform Resource Identifier
>   (URI) fragment**, subject to Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)
>   semantics. For example, `GetString("Caption%20")` is treated as
>   `GetString("Caption ")`. Do not use `"?"` or `"#"` in resource identifiers,
>   as they terminate the named resource path. For example, `"Foo?3"` is
>   treated as `"Foo"`.

Comment: I did read the document about it and it didn't talk about the colon so I asked a question here...And I don't have too much knowledge about uri semantics....